# Как убрать отступы, создающиеся по краям сайта?

Tags: html, css

Мучают белые полоски отступов, портящие внешний вид моего сайта. Как от них следует избавляться?

Comment: Напрашивается ответ "узнать чем они вызваны и убрать это". Но сделать это можете только вы сами, ваш же проект, вам лучше знать где что.

Comment: // Remove default margins, fix height
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще это может быть margin у body, который задает user-agent (в chrome - это 8px).
Попробуйте обнулить стили или как минимум margin у body.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о шапке сайта(footer) которая заключена в div и вы хотите прижать её к краям экрана, то код CSS:

```
div{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Эти свойства CSS могут помочь решить проблему, однако будьте осторожны с абсолютным позиционированием - для остальных элементов на странице ваш футер перестанет существовать и они могут повести себя непредсказуемо. Если absolute не подходит, попробуйте `position:fixed;`